# Setting One-One Relationship in DB-First Approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, db-first

I have a table structure as follows

```
FeedbackTable
  Id
  Name
  ...
  ...

ApprovalTable
  Id
  FeedbackId
  ...
  ...
```

FeedbackTable and ApprovalTable is having 1-1 relation.When i generated Model (using Database First Approach) `Feedback model` is having `icollection` of `Approval Table`.I need to change to 1-1 relation with navigation in the actual model class.

How can I do it?
Is it possible to set 1-1 relation from the database itself before creating model?

**StudentFeedback Model**

```
 public partial class StudentFeedback
 {
    public StudentFeedback()
    {
        this.StudentProjectApprovals = new HashSet<StudentProjectApproval>();
    }

 ...
 ...
 ...
 public virtual Icollection<StudentProjectApproval> StudentProjectApprovals { get; set; }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the schema you are providing to DB-First doesn't express a 1-1 relationship, it is a 1-N relationship, hence EF will treat as such.

> How can I do it?

By making `FeedbackId` both a foreign key and a primary key. You will also need to remove the `Id` column from the `ApprovalTable` table

Comment: If I remove `Id` column from the ApprovalTable then what will be its primary Key??

Comment: @ksg as I said in the answer, `FeedbackId` MUST be your primary key and your foreign key at the same time...